# Displaying elements based on search

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, loops

I would like the .box elements to show/hide based on the words the user searches for, so for example if a user types in 'Title2 Title1' because those words exists inside box one and two they will remain visible with the renaming .box elements hiding. All the text within the .box elements needs to be searchable not just that in the .title element.

Below is how far I've got. It's almost there but it's not quite working as hoped.

Any help would be great.

Many thanks.

```
<input placeholder="Search" id="search" type="text" />

<div class="box">
   <div class="title">Box Title1</div>
   <div class="content">
      Box title one content
   </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
   <div class="title">Box Title2</div>
   <div class="content">
      Box title two content
   </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
   <div class="title">Box Title3</div>
   <div class="content">
      Box title three content
   </div>
</div>

<script>
$("#search").on("input", function () {

   var search = $(this).val();

   if (search !== "") {

      var searchArray = search.split(" ");

      searchArray.forEach(function(searchWord) {

         $(".box").each(function () {

            if($(this).is(':contains('+ searchWord +')')) {
               $(this).show();
            } else {
               $(this).hide();
            }

         });

   });

   } else {
      $(".box").show();
   }

});
</script>
```

Comment: You should explain more on the remaining part you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide all box before iterate, then only show when match any words:

```js
$("#search").on("input", function () {

   var search = $(this).val();

   if (search !== "") {

      var searchArray = search.split(" ");

      // Hide all .box
      $(".box").each(function () {
        $(this).hide();
      })
      
      searchArray.forEach(function(searchWord) {         
         $(".box").each(function () {
            if($(this).is(':contains('+ searchWord +')') ) {
               $(this).show();
            }

         });

   });

   } else {
      $(".box").show();
   }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input placeholder="Search" id="search" type="text" />

<div class="box">
   <div class="title">Box Title1</div>
   <div class="content">
      Box title one content
   </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
   <div class="title">Box Title2</div>
   <div class="content">
      Box title two content
   </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
   <div class="title">Box Title3</div>
   <div class="content">
      Box title three content
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different search method. `:contains` does not work as you expect. Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function filter(e) {
    var term = $(e.target).val();
    if (term.length < 3) {
      $(".box").show();
      return;
    }
    $(".box").each(function(i, el) {
      if ($(".content", el).text().indexOf(term) >= 0) {
        $(el).show();
      } else {
        $(el).hide();
      }
    });
  }
  $("#search").keyup(filter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Search" id="search" type="text" />

<div class="box">
  <div class="title">Box Title1</div>
  <div class="content">Box title one content</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="title">Box Title2</div>
  <div class="content">Box title two content</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="title">Box Title3</div>
  <div class="content">Box title three content</div>
</div>
```

So for example if `on` is entered, no filtering is performed. If `one` is entered, the script will look inside the `content` class of each `box` and if `one` is found in the text, it will be shown otherwise, it is hidden. If the User clears their search out, all items are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all `.box`s and using regex pattern matching, check either the title or content matches the search query. Show all matched boxes and hide all others

I have also fiddled it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L8z3pbmn/)

```
$("#search").on("input", function () {

      var searchables=$('.box');
      console.log(searchables)
      var query=$(this).val();
      searchables.each(function(i,item){

      var title=$(item).find('.title').text();     
      var content=$(item).find('.content').text();
      var rgx=new RegExp(query,'gi');

      if(rgx.test(title) || rgx.test(content))
      {
                $(item).show();               
      }
      else
      {
                $(item).hide(); 
      }


    })
})
```